# Formatting string in Java

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm new to java so this is going to seem a bit tame. Anyway, in objC, when I want to insert a variable into a string, I would do it like this:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test%i", variable];
```

How do I do this in java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are number of ways, but the `java.lang.String.format()` method is an easy one:

```
String message = String.format("There are %d ways to leave your lover", 50);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method. Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for understanding all the different formatting options available.